# Rule Of Halves Buttons

Tags: python, scripting

So in my script I have it where in the <kbd>F6</kbd> *menu* you can pull a slider or input `a value manually. However what would it take to add a button on both sides that would divide by 2 and multiply by 2 using the value that was input.

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    box = layout.box()
    # DRAW YOUR PROPERTIES IN A BOX
    box.prop( self, 'ssharpangle', text = "SsharpAngle" )
    box.prop( self, 'angle', text = "SmoothingAngle" )
    box.prop( self, 'bevelwidth', text = "BevelWidth")
    box.prop( self, 'applyall', text = "ApplyAll")
```

For this example I mean on both sides of the bevel width.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using update

In your operator add a property

```
double_angle = BoolProperty(update=self.double_angle)
```

Add a double_angle method to your operator

```
class sharpenOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    '''ToolTip'''
    
    def double_angle(self, context):
        if self.double_angle:
            self.angle *= 2
            self.double_angle = False
```

Add to the draw method

```
    row = box.row(align=True)
    sub = row.row()
    sub.alignment = 'LEFT'
    sub.prop(self, "double_angle", text="", icon='X')
    
    row.prop(self, "angle", slider=True)
    sub = row.row()
    sub.alignment = 'RIGHT'
    
    sub.enabled = self.angle < radians(90) # doesn't work in F6
    sub.prop(self, "double_angle", text="", icon='X')
```